# How do I prevent an included PHP script from changing the Location URL?

Tags: php, url, redirect, location

I'm including a PHP script that changes the URL.

```
// index.php
ob_start();
include "script.php";
   // This script redirects using  header("Location:");
$out = ob_get_clean();
// I use the $out data for calculations
echo $out;
```

Is there a simple way to counter or undo this unwanted redirect? How about:

```
header("Location: index.php");   // redirect back to self
```

But this causes an endless redirect loop... any ideas?

Or is there a way to strip out the header() calls from the $out buffer, preventing it from ever reaching the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for future references. As of PHP 5.3 there's a new function called [header_remove()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php) which helps dealing with such situations.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to overwrite that header field with an invalid value, such as:

```
header('Location: ', true);
```

But I don’t know how the clients react on that.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a good way to do that. Two things come to mind:

1. Open script.php as a text file, strip out any header() commands and then eval() the result.
2. Echo a space before you include script.php and then trap the warning that PHP generates about issuing a header() after the output has already started. You'd need to echo the space before your output buffering.

Answer (score 1):

What about including the file first as a variable with `file_get_contents()`, stripping out the unwanted headers and then running it with PHP code (I won't mention the evil word used to parse a PHP string as PHP code)?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have PHP5.3 at your disposal (you probably don't), [Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091275/how-do-i-prevent-an-included-php-script-from-changing-the-location-url/1091286#1091286) does not work and you don't want to use eval, then the only other option I can see, is the use of [streams](http://www.php.net/streams). This is however yet another, more flexible but complex, form of eval. Streams, combined with [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php), and you'll be able to get rid of that function call with a simple:

```
require 'no-header://script.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the complete text in a string before you output it, you can simple remove the headers you want with a search and replace (using a regex for example).